# Singed fling on Blitzcrank who grabs someone => result?

Tags: league-of-legends

What happens if a Singed flings a Blitzcrank who grabs someone ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The person Blitz grabs is pulled to where Blitz was where he was when he used his q, not where Blitz ends up.